Decompose portfolio in factor risk
I am reading the risk chapter of Grinold Active Portfolio Managment. I understand how to calculated specific and factor risk of my portfolio, what I don't understand is how to calculate how much risk I have in each factor.
For example, given the following:
$\sigma^2_p = w \textbf{S} w = w \textbf{X} \textbf{F} \textbf{X}^T w' + w \textbf{O} w'$
where:
S is portoflio covariance matrix
X is the factor exposure
w is my holding position
F is my factor covariance matrix
O is diagonal matrix of specific variance
how do I calculate how much risk I have in each factor? Basically, I am trying to decompose my portoflio in each direction of risk.

I am also reading up on this recently.
Since you are not looking at the specific variance, you should ignore $w^TOw$, where I treat $w$ are column vectors (different notation from you).
If we look at the factor variance, we have $w^TX^TFXw$. Assuming we have $f$ number of factors and $n$ number of assets, the matrices are of the following dimensions:

$w$ is $n \times 1$ and $w^T$ is $1 \times n$
$X$ is $f \times n$ and $X^T$ is $n \times f$
$F$ is $f \times f$

We can perform the matrix multiplication of $w^TX^T = W^T$ and $Xw = W$ first, obtaining the position-weighted factor exposures of dimensions of $1 \times f$ and $f \times 1$, respectively.
Once you move onto $W^TFW$, it becomes a double summation if I recall correctly. You need to organize the double summation such that they are separated into their factor risks. This should work!

that would be the factor exposue not the factor risk

I am talking about the components of the product of $W^T F W$. Please read my explanation carefully before responding. The factor exposure you are talking about is $X$.
